# Jest spiedOn method is not called, but called once change the test case order

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

- The Spied on code is not called when the test is at the second position. (or a second `render`) and test case fails
- Test case passes if the test case is at the first position(or on first render).

Using a very basic create-react-app OOTB example and simplifying it even more for a MCVE:

MyModule.js

```
import React from 'react';
import someClass from './someClass';

function App() {
  someClass.track("someevent");
  return null;
}

export default App;
```

someClass.js

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.someProp = null;
  }
  getSatellite() {
      return {
        track: () => {}
      };
  }
  track(someProp) {
    ///THIS BELOW IF CLAUSE IS THE PROBLEM
    if (this.someProp === someProp) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.someProp = someProp;
    }
    ///////////////////////
    this.getSatellite().track('someevent');
  }
}

const instance = new SomeClass();

export default instance;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import MyModule from './MyModule'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyModule />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import someClass from './someClass';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
});

// it works if this test case is first one, weird :-| 
test('renders class', () => {
  const track = jest.fn();
  jest.spyOn(someClass, 'getSatellite').mockImplementation(()=>{
    console.log('here i am');
    return {
      track
    }
  })
  render(<App />);
  expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Output:

```
  ✓ renders learn react link (17ms)
  ✕ renders class (5ms)

  ● renders class

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      18 |   })
      19 |   render(<App />);
    > 20 |   expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                 ^
      21 | });
      22 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:20:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.472s
```

Let me know if you need anything in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

In the first `render(<App />)` the `someProp` of `someClass` is being set as `someevent`.

Now in the next render I am only mocking the function call, but not resetting the `someProp`. That's why the `if (this.someProp === someProp)` is taking effect.

So I need to reset the `someProp` to another value or `null` and it will work fine.